# how to rewrite this code in netlogo 6.1.1?

Tags: netlogo

i'm transfering my code from net logo 3.1.5  to netlogo 6.1.1. i couldn't know how to make this line works in the new version. this is the code line in netlogo 3.1.5  **and it works**:

```
set d0 sort-by [length ?1 <= length ?2] d0
```

this line means sort the list d0 from the little to the big value and when finishing put the result in d0 again.

the `[length ?1 <= length ?2]` meanse compare the value of the temporary variable named ?1 with the value of temporary variable named ?2

in netlogo 6.1.1 it tells me that **nothing named ?1 has been defined**

can you please help me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NetLogo dictionary is available at https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html It is a good starting point for finding the new syntax of any of the primitives you will have in your v3 code. In this case, one of the examples for `sort-by` is to sort on the length of a string. I'm guessing that the contents of d0 are strings - it' not clear from your question because you talk about sorting from small to large values but you have `length` in your code.

Assuming that you are sorting by length, here is the exact example as given in the dictionary:

```
show sort-by [ [string1 string2] -> length string1 < length string2 ] ["Grumpy" "Doc" "Happy"]
```

gives ["Doc" "Happy" "Grumpy"]

Translating to your case, you probably want:

```
set d0 sort-by [ [s1 s2] length s1 <= length s2] d0
```

Comment: d0 is a list of turtles ID, it's composed of sub-lists. d0 should look like this before that line code : d0[[28 50] [26 18 45] [21] [24] [42] [53] [32 44 23 25] [46] [27 38] [36 39] [34] [51 15] [43] [47] [33] [30] [40]]                                                                                                  and after that line it should look like this:                                                                    d0 [[21] [24] [42] [53] [46] [34] [43] [47] [33] [30] [40] [28 50] [27 38] [36 39] [51 15] [26 18 45] [32 44 23 25]]

Comment: i wrote it this way and it works thank you again :)                                                                     set d0 sort-by [ [list1 list2] -> length list1 < length list2] d0